# Android - save pdf with image using Mupdf

Tags: android, pdf, view, mupdf

I am developing an android application.

> My Aim:

The user can view the PDF files and they can add their signatures.

> What I did:

I have used the MUPDF library to show the PDF files to the users.
Now the user can directly add their signatures over the PDF.

> What I want:

But I want to add the signature images over the PDF and want to save it.
Is it possible add the image over the PDF and save it by using MUPDF?

Can anybody give me the idea to do this?

Comment: Did you find solution?